# Get the next immediate numeric substring in a PHP string

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm having the some following string :

```
Total: 14,785 | Daily: 4785
Total: 14,785 |
Total: 14,785 
Total: 14,785
```

Now I want to grab the numeric string from the whole like "14,785"

How to do this by using preg_match or something else. I did the following trick

```
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);
    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}
```

But it will only work if "|" will be there. What can I try to fix this?

Comment: What are `$start` and `$end`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression with a capture group:

```
preg_match('/^Total: ([\d,]+)/', $content, $match);
$number = $match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

https://regexr.com/398nc

Regex:

```
Total: ([\d,]*)
```

Comment: That also matches `14x785` in `Total: 14x785`.

Comment: @Barmar yes, you're right. Your regex looks correct.